# ElasticSearch don't return "deletebyquery" task when I query list of tasks

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using ElasticSearch 7.1.1 and use delete_by_query API to remove required documents asynchronously. As result that query return to me task id. When I execute next query:

```
GET {elasticsearch_cluster_url}/_tasks/{taskId}
```

I'm able to get correspond document for the task. But when I try to execute such query:

```
GET {elasticsearch_cluster_url}/_tasks?detailed=true&actions=*/delete/byquery
```

I don't see my task in the result list.

I also tried to execute such query:

```
GET {elasticsearch_cluster_url}/_tasks
```

And I got such response:

```
{
    "nodes": {
        "hWZQF7w_Rs6_ZRDZkGpSwQ": {
            "name": "0d5027c3ae6f0bb0105dcdb04470af43",
            "roles": [
                "master"
                ,
                "data"
                ,
                "ingest"
            ],
            "tasks": {
                "hWZQF7w_Rs6_ZRDZkGpSwQ:194259297": {
                    "node": "hWZQF7w_Rs6_ZRDZkGpSwQ",
                    "id": 194259297,
                    "type": "transport",
                    "action": "cluster:monitor/tasks/lists",
                    "start_time_in_millis": 1596710876682,
                    "running_time_in_nanos": 214507,
                    "cancellable": false,
                    "headers": { }
                },
                "hWZQF7w_Rs6_ZRDZkGpSwQ:194259298": {
                    "node": "hWZQF7w_Rs6_ZRDZkGpSwQ",
                    "id": 194259298,
                    "type": "direct",
                    "action": "cluster:monitor/tasks/lists[n]",
                    "start_time_in_millis": 1596710876682,
                    "running_time_in_nanos": 84696,
                    "cancellable": false,
                    "parent_task_id": "hWZQF7w_Rs6_ZRDZkGlDwQ:194259297",
                    "headers": { }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure, maybe that query returns the tasks only from one cluster's node that accepted the query? Why my task is missed in the last query? Is there some mistake in my query parameters?

Comment: Can you try `*byquery` instead of `*/delete/byquery`?

Comment: @Val actually I tried it, but also couldn't to get my task in response.

Comment: Can you show the full response you get from `GET _tasks` ?

Comment: @Val I used such query: GET {es_url}/_tasks/?detailed=true&actions=*byquery. I'll add response to the post

Comment: No just `GET _tasks` please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your delete by query call is very short-lived, you're not going to see it in `_tasks` after the query has run.

If you want to keep a trace of your calls, you need to add `?wait_for_completion=false` to your call.

While the query is running, you're going to see it using `GET _tasks`, however, when the query has finished running, you won't see it anymore using `GET _tasks`, but `GET .tasks/_search` instead.

After it's done running and you have specified `wait_for_completion=false`, you can see the details of your finished task with `GET .tasks/task/<task-id>`

Comment: I  use 'wait_for_completion=false' and I'm able to get task using 'GET .tasks/task/<task-id>', but can I get the list of all such my tasks filtering by 'deletebyquery' action type? My initial question about that

Comment: If you're able to get `GET .tasks/task/<task-id>` it means the task is finished, so it won't show up using `GET _tasks` anymore. You can catch them using `GET _tasks?actions=*byquery&detailed` only while they are running

Comment: thank you for the clarification, it helped me to figure out how to do what I wanted in the another way :)